# Move Files that ends with .pdf to selected folder (Python)

Tags: python

My script I run will be on my mac.

My root is '/Users/johnle/Desktop/'
The purpose of the code is to move a tons of files.
On my desktop will be tons of .pdf files. I want to move the pdf files to '/Users/johnle/Desktop/PDF'

So : '/Users/johnle/Desktop/file.pdf' - > '/Users/johnle/Desktop/PDF/'

This is my code in python :

```
def moveFile(root,number_of_files, to):

     list_of_file = os.listdir(root)

     list_of_file.sort()

    for file in list_of_file:
        name = root + str(file)

         dest = to + str(file)

         shutil.move( name, dest )
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Actually. Everything works correctly except for shutil.move.

Comment: `mv ~/Desktop/*.pdf ~/Desktop/PDF`. Done.

Comment: You've given a code fragment, not a complete file or even a second code snippet showing how you're calling this function, and you've said it "doesn't run" without explaining what errors you see. Try explaining more. Also, are you only looking to solve this problem once? If so, just run something in Terminal.app like `mkdir ~/Desktop/PDF && mv -i ~/Desktop/*.pdf ~/Desktop/PDF`. If you expect this to be a recurring problem, ask yourself why you're creating lots of files on your desktop and try to avoid doing that.

Comment: move fails as you don't join the path properly? what is the actual error?

Comment: Your code walks the entire subtree under `/Users/johnle/Desktop/`. Is that intended or you do only want pdfs in `/Users/johnle/Desktop/` specifically? Since the destination folder is one of the subdirectoriyes, if you walk the entire tree you'll end up moving already-saved pdfs on top of themselves.

Comment: My intent is to walk just '/Users/johnle/Desktop'

Comment: I upvoted jorgeh's `glob` answer. That's the way to go.

Comment: It is great. But I have the names in the array. So the time complexity is O(n^2)

Comment: @BobDylan, you should have added the error to your question as you now have two answers that don't actually address your own code at all

Comment: LOL. Sorry man. much love

Comment: Your own code would more than likely work if you used `os.path.join`  to join the paths correctly

Comment: A few notes: 1) whitespace is very important in Python. 2) Consistency is absolutely paramount in programming. You are not following either of these two rules here. Indentation should *always* be four spaces (not tabs), no more, no less. Yours is all over the place - it works for this small snippet, but as you get into more nested code, you'll get all sorts of errors.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `glob` and `shutil` modules. For example:

```
import glob
import shutil

for f in glob.glob('/Users/johnle/Desktop/*.pdf'):
    shutil.copy(f, '/Users/johnle/Desktop/PDF')
```

(this code hasn't been tested).

Note: my code copies files. If you want to move them, then replace `shutil.copy` with `shutil.move`.

Comment: Amazing. My goal in my CS career is to be smart like you.

Comment: Glad it helped. If this is the answer of your choice, don't forget to accept it (or if you prefer another answer, accept that one). That's how we keep this community alive ;)

Answer (score 4):

In case you have .pdf files with inconsistent casing on their extensions (e.g. .PDF, .pdf, .PdF, ...), you can use something like this:

```
import os
import shutil
SOURCE_DIR = '/Users/johnle/Desktop/'
DEST_DIR = '/Users/johnle/Desktop/PDF/'

for fname in os.listdir(SOURCE_DIR):
    if fname.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, fname), DEST_DIR)
```

Comment: plus one for including `join` which is most probably the issue in the OP's own code.

Answer (score 1):

The `os` module has lots of fun toys like this for manipulating files and other OS related operations.

You can use the `rename` function within the `os` module, to move the file to a new location.

```
import os
os.mkdir(<path>) #creates a new folder at the specified path
os.rename(<original/current path>, <new path>)
```

Comment: How would this be different to the OP using `shutil.move` bar it will fail if a file already exists?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham They get the same thing done regardless. I'm just more of an `os` module fan than `shutil` personally.

Comment: rename will fail where move will not, it calls rename under the hood anyway so there is no difference

Comment: @PadraicCunningham While, `rename` may fail, it'll produce and error for a file overwrite when it happens that can be caught and handled, while with `move` the original file is deleted and overwritten with the new file if there is an overwrite. I would much rather handle an exception than lose data from an overwritten file without warning.

Comment: if you are using move you should know what it does, this answer still does not actually help the OP as it is completely irrelevant to the actual issue

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't understand what you're trying to argue about....I know what `move` does....and my answer is relevant. He asked for a method of moving files to a subfolder within a directory, and this is one way.

Comment: You provided the OP with what they are already using, how is that an answer? This is not really even a comment.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham haha nowhere in his code segment was `mkdir` or `rename` being used! Take your petty arguments elsewhere.

Comment: lol,  you should read the docs when you are not too busy not answering questions https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py#l265